# Opening Word Doc 2016/2013 (or editing doc) causes Windows 10 to freeze

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, freeze

I have a new computer workstation with ASUS X99-E MB, I7, 64 GB Ram with Windows 8.1 installed and then upgraded to Windows 10.

Office 2016 was installed after upgrade to Windows 10.

Opening a Word doc will sometimes cause the system to totally freeze. Mouse and keyboard dead. Video frozen in time.

I uninstalled Office 2016 and installed Office 2013 but the behavior persists.

have googled around and tried uninstalling anti-virus programs but no luck.

Comment: 64GB RAM, really?.. I had similar issues. They were probably caused by a buggy windows update. It resolved automatically in the next updates. I'm using windows 10 64bit too.

Comment: I believe that you are correct. I have tried changing virus checkers, using Windows 8.1 and 10, using Word 2013 and 2016, rolling back video driver to known stable version, and updating the BIOS. I hope that a new update will be released soon as I have to work around the issue now. ...Oh, I need the 64 GB RAM for building large solutions, running DB servers, and running virtual machines.

Comment: Have you visited the [known issues?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Known-issues-with-Office-and-Windows-10-28d56d84-c16c-4763-8eac-e51e05a37a16)

Comment: Thanks, I looked there but didn't find the culprit. My pesky freezing actually returned, with Excel also. I now suspect one-drive. I followed the procedure below  to disable One Drive and the issue has gone away again. Knock on wood! http://www.howtogeek.com/225973/how-to-disable-onedrive-and-remove-it-from-file-explorer-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem enterprise wide with Excel and Win 10.  Had to disable Protected View (which is a terrible workaround).  Haven't experienced it in Word, but test this and see if it works:

Instructions may vary depending on which version of Office you have:

Open a blank Word doc.  File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings... > Protected View > Deselect the checkboxes next to all 3 enable params > Close/reopen program

See if that helps.  If not- go back in and re-enable protected view.

Comment: Thanks but opening word now causes a hard system crash, bypassing blue screen. A new symptom. I will use Open Office for the short term.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be the correct answer! I called the computer vendor and the support Tech advised me to do the following:

Open up an Office document, I chose Excel, go into **File > Options > Advanced and check the "Disable hardware graphics acceleration" option**. I have had no freezes since doing this a week ago and I have used Office every day.

Please note that I was also advised to reinstall the Video driver (for PNY GTX 960 2048MB PCIE 3.0 GD card) while disabling the 3D Vision options but I still experienced a freeze before I did the Office options step above.

Comment: work for me. i have old leptop with win10 os and office 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I finally updated the BIOS of my ASUS X99-E WS to version X99-E-WS-ASUS-1302. The machine hasn't frozen now in hours. It was freezing predictably before the update. I downloaded the BIOS file, X99-E-WS-ASUS-1302.CAP, from  ASUS's support site, copied it to a zip drive and followed the instructions in the motherboard manual to use the BIOS update utility from the BIOS UI.

Comment: Well this worked for about 24 hours then started predictably freezing again. I believe that it is related to Word 2016 and 2013's compatibility mode as the files were in Word 2003 format. I am able to work around it by getting the files converted to the .docx format. Tricky since I had to get Word stable again. Opening up a new Word file (.docx) with a double click seemed to do it. So the answer seems to be NVC's comment above.

Comment: I suppose you could include this as an edit to the original Q, since it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is no "accident" as it is happening at this very moment on 4 of my clients' computers at 4 different offices, all within a couple of weeks of each other.  The computers are all configured almost identically; the only difference is that 2 are running the 32-bit version of the Windows 10 Professional Creator's Update and 2 are running the 64-bit version.  They are all running Office 2016 Home and Business with all the latest updates applied along with 32GB of RAM and at least 1TB of hard drive space along with i7 processors.  The computer below is a sample of what I'm looking at here.

Word (from Office 2016 Home & Business) has started hanging (freezing-up) upon saving a file or exiting from the program - I have to use the Task Manager to shut it down; it used to work just fine and no particular changes have been made to the computer recently. It is running on Windows 10 Professional Creator's Update (64-bit) on a Dell XPS 8900 computer, i7 CPU, 32GB of RAM on a new Samsung 960 EVO 1TB SSD with NVMe enabled.  Office has been updated to the latest release and everything else runs fast and with no problems whatsoever.  I performed a fresh install of both Windows 10 Pro and Office 2016, plus I've run the "Office Repair Tool" to no avail (meaning it found no problems with Office).
There is one very curious thing, which seems to be straight out of the Twilight Zone; through over 100 hours of trial and error research, doing everything I could think of to troubleshoot this problem, I've found that removing any and all old ".tif" (Tagged Image File Format) files from the Windows default "Documents" directory (including from any subfolders which might also be in there) seems to help significantly.  I can't say that it's solved the problem but the dead lockups of Word (and Excel, for that matter) seem to have abated quite a bit.  I would be interested to see if anybody else with this problem has any of these ".tif" files still hanging around and if removing them (to a flash drive or whatever) makes any difference in the Word lockup problem.  With the advent of PDF files they seem to be dinosaurs anyway but a lot of folks may still have some of these things floating about in their Documents directory.
Notwithstanding that, there unquestionably has been some kind of bad update, either to the Windows 10 Creator's Update or Office 2016, which has recently caused this because 4 (and possibly more - I'm waiting for the phone calls to start on Monday morning) different computers have fallen victim to it in less than 2 weeks now.  Any comments and / or input from "out in the field" would be most welcome.

Also, I just got this tidbit from another Forum; it's definitely worth looking into if you happen to use Malwarebytes, as all my clients do...
[Possible Solution To The Problem](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-crashes-or-hangs-in-Windows-10-Creators-Update-with-Malwarebytes-3-0-7a59dfbc-5997-4798-903e-a9e709f17692?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Office freezing when attempting to open or insert documents or pictures fron the Windows 10 filesystem.

On reading here about the issue with Malwarebytes the problem was immediately resolved by quitting Malwatebytes.  I upgraded Malwarebytes to 3.1.2 beta and the problem had gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Its the display driver problem. disable hardware acceleration in office 2016 and uninstall and reinstall display driver of PC. problem solved for the time being. tks